# Css for sub ul to display inline vertically to main ul

Tags: html, css

I am trying to test a layout where I will have a small image with file details below it.

I setup the html and css to use a ul tag with list items. It display like this
[image]

I want the file properties (for now I just used three but there may be more) to display under the image with the left edges of the image and the file headings aligned. I cant seem to get them below the image and aligned. Many tries but they always seem to be on right of image.[image]

```css
div {
  width: 660px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li ul {
  display: block;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
}

li img {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}

li img:hover {
  border: 5px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/xixeyesbz/image_grid.png"></a>

        <ul>
          <li><b>File:</b> DeWalt_GE_FullView.jpg</li>
          <li><b>Size:</b> 43,657 bytes</li>
          <li><b>Type:</b> image/jpeg</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/xixeyesbz/image_grid.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/xixeyesbz/image_grid.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/xixeyesbz/image_grid.png"></a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you floating the image to the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest getting rid of the floats, restructuring your code so it's not so confusing with li's and ul's, and then try using flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: auto;
}

.file-box {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}


.file-box img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #333;
}

.file-box img:hover {
    border: 5px solid lightblue;
}


.file-details p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="file-box">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/xixeyesbz/image_grid.png"></a>
  <div class="file-details">
   <p>File: DeWalt_GE_FullView.jpg</p>
   <p>Size: 43,657 bytes</p>
   <p>Type: image/jpeg</p>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="file-box">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/xixeyesbz/image_grid.png"></a>
  <div class="file-details">
   <p>File: DeWalt_GE_FullView2.jpg</p>
   <p>Size: 44,657 bytes</p>
   <p>Type: image/jpeg</p>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="file-box">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/xixeyesbz/image_grid.png"></a>
  <div class="file-details">
   <p>File: DeWalt_GE_FullView3.jpg</p>
   <p>Size: 45,657 bytes</p>
   <p>Type: image/jpeg</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @StefanBob...not a css regular, just trying to build some admin tools..didnt know about flexbox..Looks good but id like to eliminate the spacing between lines for space saving..I guess I could change the css for the p tags you used.

Comment: Yea i was gonna say change to span tags, but then they won't wrap unless you set spans to display: block; Might as well change p margin to 0. I edited answer

Comment: Your snippet runs right, but in my mvc page the text is right indented about 5-10px